java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop [Jenkins Pipeline]
Terms:
UT = unit tests
IT = integration tests
Issue:
The following error comes up when I try to build the code on Jenkins. The code contains UT and IT based on Java 17, Maven 3.6.0 and Testcontainers. All the tests are running OK locally but failing on Jenkins pipeline on IT stage. Jenkinsfile at the end.
Error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:60)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:49)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:87)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:82)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:69)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NioTransportFactory.newEventLoopGroup(NioTransportFactory.java:32)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NioTransportFactory.newEventLoopGroup(NioTransportFactory.java:21)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.ChannelManager.<init>(ChannelManager.java:133)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClient.<init>(DefaultAsyncHttpClient.java:92)

    at org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.http.AsyncHttpConnector.<init>(AsyncHttpConnector.java:183)

    at org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.http.AsyncHttpConnectorProvider.getConnector(AsyncHttpConnectorProvider.java:52)

    at org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.PulsarAdminImpl.<init>(PulsarAdminImpl.java:150)

    at org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.PulsarAdminBuilderImpl.build(PulsarAdminBuilderImpl.java:44)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)

    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)

    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)

    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)

    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)

    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)

    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)

    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)

    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)

    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)

    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:56)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)

Caused by: org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:179)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:146)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:183)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:38)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)

    ... 61 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EventFD.eventfd0(Native Method)

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EventFD.<init>(EventFD.java:40)

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:82)

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36)

    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:177)

    ... 65 more

Jenkinsfile:
#!/usr/bin/env groovy


def java = null
def maven = null
def mavenEnv = null
def version = null
def mvnLocalHome = "/path/to/local/"
def img = null


def wasManuallyKickedOff() {
    return currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()[0].class.toString().endsWith('UserIdCause')
}

def isRelease() {
    return env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' && wasManuallyKickedOff()
}

def currentVersion(mavenEnv) {
    withEnv(mavenEnv) {
        def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
        def version = sh script: "echo ${pom.getVersion().trim()} | grep -Eo '[0-9\\.]+'", returnStdout: true
        return version.trim()
    }
}

def createVersion(version) {
    version = version + (isRelease() ? '' : "-${env.BRANCH_NAME}-SNAPSHOT")
    return version
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'docker'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                script {
                    checkout scm
                    java = tool name: 'Eclipse Temurin openjdk17-17.0.6_10', type: 'jdk'
                    maven = tool name: 'maven 3.6.0', type: 'maven'
                    mavenEnv = ["MVN_HOME=${maven}", "JAVA_HOME=${java}", "PATH+MAVEN=${maven}/bin"]
                    sh 'echo from here *****************************************'
                    sh 'echo ${JAVA_HOME}'
                    version = createVersion(currentVersion(mavenEnv))
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build and unit test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withEnv(mavenEnv) {
                        sh 'echo "testcontainers.reuse.enable=true" > /opt/jenkins/.testcontainers.properties'
                        sh "mvn clean test install -B -U -e -Dmaven.repo.local=${mvnLocalHome} -DskipITs"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('(**PRODUCTION Version) ITs: "datastax/lunastreaming-all:3.1_4.6"') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withEnv(mavenEnv) {
                        sh "mvn clean verify -pl integration-tests -Dmaven.repo.local=${mvnLocalHome} -P datastax_lunastreaming_all_3_1_4_6"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Push') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withEnv(mavenEnv) {
                        if (isRelease()) {
                            sh "mvn -Dresume=false release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -Dmaven.repo.local=${mvnLocalHome}"
                        } else {
                            sh "mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${version} -Dmaven.repo.local=${mvnLocalHome}"
                            sh "mvn deploy -DskipTests -Dmaven.repo.local=${mvnLocalHome}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried to add the following stage in Jenkinsfile. ulimit -n is 8192. I want to change it to 16384 but it gives the error: line 1: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
Stage
stage('Check limits') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'ulimit -n 16383'
                    sh 'ulimit -n'
                    sh 'ulimit -n -S'
                    sh 'ulimit -n -H'
                }
            }
        }


I'd assume that ulimit requires privilege escalation on your system, and this is the very last thing to do from a CI build. I'm also not sure this question is suitable for StackOverflow.

Thanks for the reply. What should I do next? Any solution from your side. Thanks in advance!
